# неработает пользовательская анимация с wow.js

Tags: jquery, css

Хочу сделать так чтобы при прокрутке вниз сработала моя анимация для этого пишу следующее

```
<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>
<div class="wow div1" data-wow-offset="200"></div>
<style>
.div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: example;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
    }
    25% {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
</style>
```

но почемуто неработает,в чём моет быть дело?

Comment: объявите `new WOW().init();`  перед закрывающим тегом **body**

Answer (score 2):

вот ссылка на codepan [link](http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/XKOyRb) все работает

добавил эти строки

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js">
</script>
```